# Can we select group in drop down list in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to show some data in the form of groups in drop down list. Can we select a group instead of a group member in order to select full group in drop down list. If yes then how, if no then any other way or ant other control which can be used?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean can you collect a sub-set of options within a `select` box of a form, then yes, I believe you can:

```
      <form method="post" action="" enctype="form/multipart">
        <fieldset>
          <select>
            <optgroup label="numbers">
              <option>One</option>
              <option>Two</option>
              <option>Three</option>
            </optgroup>

            <optgroup label="letters">
              <option>a</option>
              <option>b</option>
              <option>c</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

demo at: http://jsbin.com/iwada3/edit
```

---

Edited after realising I'm a moron, and addressing the question that was really asked (I'm sorry, long day...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
      function() {
       $('option.all').click(
         function() {
           $(this).parent().children().attr('selected','selected');
           $(this).attr('selected','');
         }
         );
      }
      );

  </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <select multiple>
        <optgroup class="num" label="numbers">
          <option class="num all">Select all:</option>
          <option class="num">One</option>
          <option class="num">Two</option>
          <option class="num">Three</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup  class="let"label="letters">
          <option class="let all">Select all:</option>
          <option class="let">a</option>
          <option class="let">b</option>
          <option class="let">c</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo at: http://jsbin.com/ebeke3

It does require jQuery (in this version, at least), but I can't see an alternative to JS for what you require, I'm sorry to say.

If you mean something else, then I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks Ricebowl, the implementation u gave, I m already having it, but what I want is to select group name also. I mean, in your code, (One, two, three) are in numbers group, can i select NUMBERS as an option. or any other approach?

Comment: I like your answer, but I suspect OP wants to choose ALL of the group members by selecting the OPTGROUP name.  This example does not allow you to select the group name -- only the group members.

Comment: @Ashwani K, @MJB; yeah, I'm apparently a moron...I'm just working through jsbin with a few ideas that feel like they should work, but don't. I'm assuming that you/he wants to click 'numbers' and then have all child `select`s highlighted?

Comment: @RiceBowl, the childs need not be highlighted, if just the group can behave like an option?

Comment: You can't highlight the OPTGROUP and not highlighting = selecting the childs will not work. You cannot reinvent how forms work and you really shouldn't ignore how a user expects a for to react.

Comment: @Kau-Boy, who was your comment addressing? It seems customary to prefix the addressee/recipient with the '@' symbol to indicate to whom you're talking. =)