# How to create multilevel categories and populate into select option on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im working on laravel with dynamic category. I can populate to list as below code in blade.

```
   <ul id="browser" class="filetree">
      @foreach($categories as $category)
          <li class="tree-view closed">{{$category->name}}</span>
              @if(count($category->childs))
                   @include('setting.category.managechild',['childs' => $category->childs])
              @endif
          </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
```

And another child blade

```
<ul>
    @foreach($childs as $child)
        <li class="tree-view closed">
         {{ $child->name }}
            @if(count($child->childs))
                @include('setting.category.managechild',['childs' => $child->childs])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Below is result.

[image]

Btw, I would like to populate into `select option` with group separation as blow instead .

[image]

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: You can easliy do it, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821480/can-we-select-group-in-drop-down-list-in-html

Comment: Dear  alithedeveloper, Thanks I'll try.

Comment: The problem with grouping option is that you can not select the parent category (group name like some value in your exemple ) is that ok for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package in one of my project. It uses binary tree to store data. Saving is as usual. Here is the render of the category. It may help.

```php
$categories = Category::defaultOrder()->get()->toTree();
$renderedMenu = '<div><ol>';

$traverse = function ($categories) use(&$traverse, &$renderedMenu) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $childrenCount = $category->children->count();
        $renderedMenu .= '<li>'.$category->title;

        if($childrenCount > 0){
            $renderedMenu .= '<ol>';
            $traverse($category->children);
            $renderedMenu .= '</ol>';
        }
        $renderedMenu .= '</li>';
    }
};

$traverse($categories);
$renderedMenu .= '</ol></div>';
```